# Установка библиотек QT creator в Astra Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, astra-linux

Всем привет. Мне необходимо работать в Астра-Линукс и разрабатывать в нем приложения. Установив Qt creator, решил создать визуальное приложение выводящее "hello", но вывело две ошибки. Попытался гуглить - узнал что нужно установить пакет libqt4-dev, но при попытке установки через терминал выводило ошибку: пакет не найден. Прошу вашей помощи, помогите настроить QT. Заранее спасибо.
[image: код ошибки]

Comment: А для чего Астра? там если память не изменяет туго с обновлением пакетов. Ну а так да вам уже дали ответ)

Comment: Такое задание дали. Нужно разработать приложение для астры.

Comment: Возможно я сейчас сорву покров, но можно разрабатывать прложение не в астре, а только собирать там финальный проект. Такая, вот, новость.

Comment: А вы можете описать этот процесс? Я согласен, что это возможно. Но не думал о процессе.

Comment: Все конечно зависит от версии астры, но если вы там будет обновлять пакетную базу вы потеряете свою сертификацию. Можете спокойно разрабатывать и писать проект в любом другом дистрибутиве основаном на linux. А в астре достаточно потом это только собрать и тестировать.

Comment: Если мне память не изменяет, то в Астре "из коробки" установлены сразу две версии Qt: 4 и 5. При этом по умолчанию используется Qt5. Посмотрите куда ссылается ваш `qmake`: `qmake --version` и `ls -l /usr/bin/qmake`, и при необходимости перенаправьте ссылку на Qt4, например через механизм `update-alternatives`.

Comment: Возьмите нормальный дистрибутив и работайте себе спокойно :-)
Знаю разных людей, которые разрабатывают на альте, а потом собирают и на астре.

Answer (score 5):

Ты собираешь, проект в Qt5, а libqt4-dev - это либ-ы для 4-й версии. Поищи qt-devel (или qt5-devel).

P.S. Хорошим тоном было-бы скопировать текст сообщений об ошибках в текстовом виде, а не картинкой.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужна либа OpenGL и возможно все соберется. По крайней мере сейчас он ругается на ее отсутствие. Ну и сконфигурировать нужно qt в настройках qt creator'a нормально, чтобы он не ругался на неправильную конфигурацию.

Answer (score 0):

После установки QT под aststralinux sudo apt-get install qt5*
Скачайте автономный установщик версии QT 5.12.0 для Linux c сайта Qt.
Установите согласно инструкции. Там есть все библиотеки.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: При использовании автономной СДК установка кутэ в систему не нужна. Только понадобится прога чтоб собрать бандл библиотек для распространения... Не помню как называется